# wordpress function to remove first image from posts with specific category

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I am currently using this function to remove the first image from my posts, however, I need to remove the first image from posts with a specific category. Any help is much appreciated.

```
function remove_first_image ($content) {
    if (!is_page() && !is_feed() && !is_feed() && !is_home()) {
        $content = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "", $content, 1);
    } 
    return $content;
}
//add_filter('the_content', 'remove_first_image');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
function remove_first_image ($content) {

    if (!is_page() && !is_feed() && !is_feed() && !is_home()) {
        if(has_term( array( 'entertainment', 'food', 'home', 'travel' ), 'category' ) )
            $content = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "", $content, 1);
    } 

    return $content;

}
add_filter('the_content', 'remove_first_image');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [in_category](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_category) conditional functions

```
function remove_first_image ($content) {
    if ( in_category( 'catslug' ) ) {
        $content = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "", $content, 1);
    } 
    return $content;
}
//add_filter('the_content', 'remove_first_image');
```